# Filter Orders based on product_id or user_id(Vendor)

Tags: magento, filtering

I have followed [How to create a custom grid from scratch](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/) to create custom Sales Orders. Admin is creating vendors and vendors will be uploading product. I want to restrict vendors such that they can see orders placed on their own product only.
There is one new model jbmarketplace/jbmarketplaceproducts in which vendors user_id and product_id is being stored when vendor creates product. But when I'm filtering it gives **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id' in 'where clause'**. But product_id is available in sales_flat_order_item table.

## This problem is Fixed. Updated Code

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // Get current logged in user
    $current_user = Mage::getSingleton( 'admin/session' )->getUser();

    // Limit only for vendors
   if ( $current_user->getRole()->getRoleId() == Mage::getStoreConfig( 'jbmarketplace/jbmarketplace/vendors_role' ) ) {
      // echo( $current_user->getUserId());
       $my_products = Mage::getModel( 'jbmarketplace/jbmarketplaceproducts' )
           ->getCollection()
           ->addFieldToSelect( 'product_id' )
           ->addFieldToFilter( 'user_id', $current_user->getUserId() )
           ->load();
       $my_product_array = array();
       foreach ( $my_products as $product ) {
           $my_product_array[] = $product->getProductId();
           $entity = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
               ->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToSelect('order_id')
               ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$my_product_array)
               ->load();
          // echo $entity->getSelect();// will print sql query

       }
       $d=$entity->getData();

       if($d){

           $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
           // My code
             ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $d)
        ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
            'city'       => 'city',
            'country_id' => 'country_id'
        ))

         //  ->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar', 'main_table.products_id ='.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id',array('value'))
        ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
            'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
        ))


            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'fullname',
            'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
            array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'products',
            '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                    AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
            array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
        )

       ;
         parent::_prepareCollection();
       $this->setCollection($collection);
    return $this;

   }
       else
       {
           echo("Current there are no purchases on your product. Thank you");
       }
   }
   else{
       echo("Please Login as Vendor and you will see orders on your products.<br>");
      // $current_user = Mage::getSingleton( 'admin/session' )->getUser()->getUserId();
      // echo($current_user);
    }
```

}

Comment: Problem Fixed.For someone who want to use it, please check the updated code above.

Comment: you should answer your own question then ;-)

Comment: I do follow @JeyDWork on that remark, the way you should have done it would have be to leave your question unmodified and then to answer yourself with the correct code to finally accept your own answer as the good one.

Comment: I'll remember that next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which worked for me.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // Get current logged in user
    $current_user = Mage::getSingleton( 'admin/session' )->getUser();

    // Limit only for vendors
   if ( $current_user->getRole()->getRoleId() == Mage::getStoreConfig( 'jbmarketplace/jbmarketplace/vendors_role' ) ) {
      // echo( $current_user->getUserId());
       $my_products = Mage::getModel( 'jbmarketplace/jbmarketplaceproducts' )
           ->getCollection()
           ->addFieldToSelect( 'product_id' )
           ->addFieldToFilter( 'user_id', $current_user->getUserId() )
           ->load();
       $my_product_array = array();
       foreach ( $my_products as $product ) {
           $my_product_array[] = $product->getProductId();
           $entity = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
               ->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToSelect('order_id')
               ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$my_product_array)
               ->load();
          // echo $entity->getSelect();// will print sql query

       }
       $d=$entity->getData();

       if($d){

           $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
           // My code
             ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $d)
        ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
            'city'       => 'city',
            'country_id' => 'country_id'
        ))

         //  ->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar', 'main_table.products_id ='.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id',array('value'))
        ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
            'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
        ))


            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'fullname',
            'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
            array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'products',
            '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                    AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
            array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
        )

       ;
         parent::_prepareCollection();
       $this->setCollection($collection);
    return $this;

   }
       else
       {
           echo("Current there are no purchases on your product. Thank you");
 }
   }
   else{
       echo("Please Login as Vendor and you will see orders on your products.<br>");
      // $current_user = Mage::getSingleton( 'admin/session' )->getUser()->getUserId();
      // echo($current_user);
    }
}
```